# Decomposition of SARIMA models

Tags: r, time-series, arima, decomposition

I use R for time series analysis. I would like to evaluate decomposition algorithms. `decompose` and `stl` from "stats" package lead to good results but often, the residuals are not meaningless.

Example:

```
dec <- decompose(AirPassengers)
Box.test(dec$random[7:138], lag = 24, type = "Ljung")
> p-value < 2.2e-16
```

There is still a lot of autocorrelation in the residuals, the same for `decompose` with `type = "multiplicative"` and for `stl`. If possible, I would like to extract all meaningful information from the residuals. Thus, I had a look on classical forecasting techniques:

```
library(forecast)
dec <- auto.arima(AirPassengers)
Box.test(dec$residuals, lag = 24, type = "Ljung")
> p-value = 0.01356
```

Fitting a SARIMA model leads to less autocorrelation and thus, better "information extraction". For p > 0.05, one could argue for a Gaussian error distribution.

Is there a way to decompose the ARIMA fit into slowly varying components and oscillating components like with classical decomposition techniques?

Comment: Interesting question. I strongly suspect that the answer is "no", but perhaps someone has a clever hack. (Incidentally, we don't have anything [tagged both "decomposition" and "arma"](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decomposition+arma) or ["decomposition" and "arima"](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decomposition+arma).)

Comment: Ignoring outliers leads to mismodeling.  There is a big outlier in March of the last year that really impacts the model. In fact, it is why LOGS was used when in fact it wasn't ever need. https://twitter.com/tomdireill/status/708029337883320320

Comment: Lars, beware of extracting too much. Trying to eliminate any and all patterns completely may result in detection of spurious patterns. Some patterns may just be due to chance. You note correcly that all *meaningful* information is of interest, though.

Comment: Thanks, @RichardHardy. I totally agree that one should not try to find too much meaningful information in noise. I am just surprised that a SARIMA model, that someway detrends and deseasonalizes a series for calculating an ARMA model, leaves less meaningful residuals than usual decomposition techniques do. Thus, I wonder whether trend and season could be retrieved.